# Website not rendering correctly in IE - Just cannot get it right. :(

Tags: html, web, internet-explorer, rendering

I have been trying to days now to get this website completed ... however, when viewing it in IE (compatibility mode) the header is all messed up. :(

The website is here: http://nageela.einfal.com/

This is actually the first design I've converted into a Wordpress theme, so it's been very challenging.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd really appreciate it, I've grown so very frustrated with this! I'm not an IE user myself, though the client is it seems.

Thanks,
Jennifer

Comment: Hi Jennifer - I'd recommend removing your CSS so your question is easier to read. The CSS can be easily viewed at your URL.

Comment: Thanks to VoteyDisciple for editing it.

Comment: I tested the site (it looks nice, btw! great job with a first-time wordpress site) in latest versions of firefox and IE8. It looks fine there. I see the problem you're talking about when using compatibility mode. However, can you confirm that the same problem occurs when actually viewed in IE7 (since that's what compatibility mode is supposed to emulate)? If not, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: One other thing, in case you're not aware: the officially-recommended way to test sites in multiple versions of IE is to use a VM. Having multiple versions of IE on one machine is not recommended.

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP? And this question also belongs to Doctype.com

Comment: The site is completely broken in IE6 - what a nightmare!  Good luck Jen.

Comment: @ eyze Sorry, Wordpress is PHP is why I did that!
@ Cory I'll remove the CSS now ...
@ Matt Thank you! And yes, looking terrible in IE7 :( I don't have multiple versions of IE, hate to admit that I've even the one I do. Lol

Comment: here's my suggestion. when using tutorials try at least be a little bit different than the final result. In fact it looks almost like you just took the ready psd from pshero.com/archives/custom-hang-tag lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout breaks mostly because of positioning issues in IE7 (and IE6). See the attached css, the lines I have changed is marked /*FIXED*/.

```
/*  
Theme Name: Camp Negeela
Author: Mafiakitty Web Design & Development
Author URI: http://www.mafiakitty.com/
Description: Custom Theme
Version: 1.0
Tags: custom, canada, mafiakitty, design, creative
*/

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
outline: none;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active {
color: #630001;
}

a:hover {
color: #134077;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

body {
background-color: #f7921e;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #666;
line-height: 1.8;
}

.newcampers {
background: url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela/img/campers.png);
width: 518px;
height: 19px;
margin-left: 58px;
cursor: default;
top: 230px;
position: absolute;
}

.bed {
background-color: #e4e2d6;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
border-left: 1px solid #333333;
border-right: 1px solid #333333;
}

#wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 960px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.floatleft {
float: left;
background: url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela/img/left.png);
margin-top: 0;
width: 43px;
height: 182px;
margin-left: 1px;
position: absolute; /* FIXED */
}

.floatright {
float: right;
background: url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela/img/leaves-top.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-top: 0;
width: 488px;
height: 334px;
right: -10px;
position: absolute;
}

.photo {
background: url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela/img/photo.png) no-repeat;
width: 275px;
height: 263px;
margin-right: 62px;
margin-top: 50px;
position: absolute; /* FIXED */
    right: 0;
}

.board {
float: right;
background: url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela//img/bg.png);
margin-top: -10px;
width: 379px;
height: 500px;
}

.board div.video {
float: right;
background: url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela/video.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 62px;
height: 108px;
margin-top: 207px;
margin-right: 175px;
}

.board a {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.board div.free {
float: right;
background: url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela/img/free.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 141px;
height: 74px;
margin-top: -215px;
margin-right: 135px;
}

.board div.pic {
float: right;
background: url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela/img/pic.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 61px;
height: 13px;
margin-top: 136px;
margin-right: 272px;
}

.board div.sign {
float: right;
background: url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela/img/sign.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 138px;
height: 46px;
margin-top: -203px;
margin-right: 15px;
}

#header {
height: 262px;
background: #e4e2d6 url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela/img/hdbg.jpg);
margin-top: 0;
padding: 0;
}

/*FIXME*/
a.logo {
width: 570px;
height: 76px;
margin-top: 37px;
margin-left: 0px;
background: url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela/img/logo.png);
position: absolute;
float: left;
left: 55px; /* FIXED */
}

a.logo span {
display: none;
}

#content {
width: 520px;
float: left;
margin-left: 24px;
padding-top: 5px;
clear: both;
padding-left: 10px;
/*margin-top: -52px; FIXED*/
    display: inline;
}

.post {
width: 520px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

.post h2 a {
color: #24446b;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 24px;
}

.post span.post-info {
color: #CCCCCC;
font-size: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
width: 560px;
float: left;
}

.post p {
line-height: 22px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.post div.cats {
border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
padding-top: 10px;
}

#sidebar {
width: 379px;
float: right;
margin-right: 0px;
}

#footer {
clear: both;
width: 960px;
height: 350px;
background: #e4e2d6 url(http://nageela.einfal.com/wp-content/themes/nageela/img/footer.jpg);
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
}

/*
    .comments template styles
*/

.comments {
float: left;
padding: 0;
}

.comments input[type=text], textarea {
width: 350px;
}

textarea {
width: 450px;
}

.comments fieldset {
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}

.comments p {
padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.comments h2 {
padding: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.aligncenter, div.aligncenter {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.alignleft {
float: left;
}

.alignright {
float: right;
}

img.avatar {
float: right;
}

.newspaper {
float: right;
background: url(img/newspaper.png) bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 382px;
height: 350px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.inner {
width: 382px;
height: 300px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#dropmenu, #dropmenu ul {
top: -80px;
list-style-type: none;
list-style-position: outside;
position: relative;
line-height: 1.5em;
z-index: 200;
width: 100%;
font-weight: bold;
}

#dropmenu {
position: absolute;
top: 180px;
}

#dropmenu a {
display: block;
padding: 0.25em 1em;
color: #f7921e;
text-decoration: none;
}

#dropmenu a:hover {
background: #711a19;
color: #fff;
}

#dropmenu li {
float: left;
position: relative;
}

#dropmenu ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
width: 12em;
top: 1.9em;
left: -1px;
}

#dropmenu ul a {
border-left: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
background: #10253a;
}

#dropmenu li ul {
border-top: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
width: 14.1em;
}

#dropmenu li ul a {
width: 12em;
height: auto;
float: left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
}

#dropmenu ul ul {
top: auto;
}

#dropmenu li ul ul {
left: 12em;
margin: 0px 0 0 10px;
}

#dropmenu li:hover ul ul, #dropmenu li:hover ul ul ul, #dropmenu li:hover ul ul ul ul {
display: none;
}

#dropmenu li:hover ul, #dropmenu li li:hover ul, #dropmenu li li li:hover ul, #dropmenu li li li li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

#contact-area {
width: 300px;
margin-left: 320px;
float: right;
position: absolute;
bottom: 40px;
}

#contact-area input, #contact-area textarea {
background-color: #61502c;
padding: 1px;
width: 125px;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
border: 2px solid #61502c;
color: #372d24;
}

#contact-area textarea {
height: 90px;
}

#contact-area textarea:focus, #contact-area input:focus {
border: 2px solid #630001;
}

#contact-area input.submit-button {
width: 61px;
height: 13px;
float: right;
background: url(img/submit.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
border: 0px;
cursor: pointer;
text-indent: -9999px;
}

label {
float: left;
text-align: right;
margin-right: 15px;
width: 100px;
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: #e4e2d6;
}

#contact-area .formin {
background: url(img/form.png);
width: 137px;
height: 37px;
position: absolute;
top: -53px;
left: 50px;
}

.contactin {
background: url(img/contact.png);
width: 270px;
height: 39px;
position: absolute;
top: -54px;
margin-left: -258px;
}

.contactin p {
float: left;
margin: 18%;
border: 0px ;
width: 80%;
display: inline;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
line-height: 2.2;
color: #ffffff;
}

.contactin a:link {
color: #f6d60b;
}

/* rotator in-page placement */
    div#rotator {
height: 245px;
position: absolute; /* FIXED */
    left: 640px; /* FIXED */
    top: 65px; /* FIXED */
}

/* rotator image style */   
    div#rotator ul li img {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 4px;
background: #FFF;
}

/* rotator css */
    div#rotator ul li {
float: right;
position: absolute;
list-style: none;
}

    div#rotator ul li.show {
z-index: 500
}
```

Comment: Omg Tomsky!

Thank you so much ... you've no idea how much I appreciate you taking the time out to do this, brought tears! LOL I've been wrestling with this for soooo long - thank you thank you thank you! :)